# Problems with documentclass{book} and utf8, prerenderunicode

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, unicode

I'm trying to write a book-like report in Greek, so at the beginning of every even page the name of the chapter is appeared and at the beginning of every odd page the name of the section is appeared. I'm using the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{% 
\markboth{#1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{% 
\markright{\thesection\ #1}} 
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line 
} 





\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Θεώρημα}[chapter]
\newenvironment{proof1}[1][Απόδειξη:]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\begin{document}

 \end{document}
```

but when I'm compiling my tex I get this at the beginning of the even pages (note that it works corectly at odd pages)
[image: broken name of chapter]

It actually says please insert prerenderunicode (something like that).

I have a template that works but runs with the `\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}` command which is outdated for my TeXnicCenter 2.0 and MikTeX 2.9,so I'm thinking that there is something like a collision between `\documentclass{book}` and `utf8x`, because when I change  `\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}` with  `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` it doesn't work at all (0 pages). With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` not even the code that I've written  works.
Does anyone had the same problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when the headers with Greek characters are being prepared. If you have an up-to-date TeX distribution, just get rid of `utf8x` and use the `utf8` option.

I added a patch for the `proof` environment that uses boldface for the word ‘Proof’ and a colon instead of the period, so you can use it instead of defining another environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage{xpatch} % for patching ‘proof’

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} 
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
  \fancyhead{}% get rid of headers on plain pages 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% and the line 
} 

\newtheorem{thm}{Θεώρημα}[chapter]
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{.}{:}{}{}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for filling with nonsense text

\begin{document}

\chapter{Θεώρημα}
\section{Απόδειξη}

\kant[1]

\begin{thm}
I don't know Greek.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
I said it.
\end{proof}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After a lot of testing,installing the latest miktex and updating packages it seems that it's working,by changing utf8x to utf8.Hope it will not change.Thank you a lot.